# trouble setting the background-image using css

Tags: html, css

(I'm using Visual Studio 2013)
I want to set a background for my web page. if I put the

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-image: url("Content/Images/back.png");
}
```

within my aspx file it will work and will set my desired background. however when I put in the css file it won't work

this is how css looks

```
body {
    background-image: url("Content/Images/back.png");
}
```

I want to mention that I have  attribute in the aspx and when I change the background color in css to test it it works . but for the background it won't work!!

here is my .aspx file ;

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="EmptyWebForm.Default" %>
<link href="Content/Styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <style type="text/css">
                /*body {
                    background-image: url("Content/Images/back.png");
                }*/
            </style>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the `.css` file in your project? And is `Content` in the same directory as the file? `url()` paths are relative to the stylesheet's path.

Comment: .css is located in Content\Styles\styles.css ! please note that when it is in the body of .aspx file it works perfectly fine so I don't thing the problem is with the path !

Comment: When it's in the body of a page, the path is relative to the page. Since you moved it into the `.css` file, you have to adjust the path accordingly. Try `url("../Images/back.png")`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I already did ! let's be more clear, do I put it in the .css file like the one Marcin Nabialek mentioned ?!  if yes then how should I call it in my aspx file ? because it's not working even with url("../Images/back.png"). I just updated my question and I have put my .aspx file !

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I delelted the browser cache and it worked ! I guess the correct path is url("../Images/back.png") which you mentioned. thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

Probably your CSS file is in different directory. Url for image is relative to css file so you should change it to for example:

```
body {
    background-image: url("../Content/Images/back.png");
}
```

You've added more code so the answer in that case will be:

```
body {
    background-image: url("../Images/back.png");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, is most likely your file path. Also, watch out for `background` vs. `background-image' etc, because in certain cases you could get tripped up since `background` assumes image and color -

Comment: thanks, I tried background-image: url("../Content/Images/back.png"); but it didn't work! please note that when it is in the body of .aspx file it works perfectly fine so I don't thing the problem is with the path !